# PHP Hit Counter... Can I Transform SESSION to COOKIE??

Tags: php, html, cookies, timer

I have been working on this for awhile now. Made a PHP counter that gets the views on a front end page, and displays the Views on a backend(cms, etc.) page.

index.php code:

```
<?php 
  function get_hits() {
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
      $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
    }
  }
?>
```

display_hits.php code:

```
<?php 
  function display_hits() {
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
      $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views'];
    } else {
      $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
    }
    echo "Total Page Views Since Browser Close = ". $_SESSION['views'];
  }
?>
<?php display_hits(); ?>
```

Main thing is I would like the Counter to stay for 7 Days and then reset. Not sure how to go about it... I know I should use setcookie(); somehow.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This a the function setcookie it takes a name, a value and a time. (3600*24*7 = 7days)

```
setcookie("pageview", $_SESSION['views'], time()+3600*24*7);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
<?php 
  function get_hits() {
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
      $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
      setcookie("counter", $_SESSION["views"], $_SESSION["days"]);
    } else {
      $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
      $_SESSION["days"] = time()+3600*24*7;
      setcookie("counter", $_SESSION["views"], time()+3600*24*7);
    }
  }
?>
```

you basically store another session variable with the time+ 7days and store it in cookie. Anytime the counter is updated you update that cookie with the new counter value and the initial time/day

Dins

Comment: This looks like it will work but I recieve "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'" For index its line "16" and for display_hits its line "7" Thanks

Comment: @JonathanStimpert.. forgot to put a semi-colon after setcookie.. this should work now..

Comment: Code fixed, But on Browser close it gets rid of the Cookie.. So will try Vanilla Cookie Manager or something else lol Thanks

Comment: Yeah Didn't seem to work haha.. Still resets on Browser Close... Almost thought all those sessions should be $_COOKIE but I could be wrong